# What's the best way to limit access to a virtual machine web server? VPN or IP limiting?

Tags: vpn, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine installed using VirtualBox. Windows 7 is the host and Ubuntu is the guest. They use a shared Dropbox folder as the DocumentRoot to allow backup and ease of development on multiple devices.

Inside my local network this setup is fine however I would like to be able to develop when I'm outside of my local network but I don't want other people to have access to any of the multiple sites on the web server.

I have a Netgear DG834G with version 5 firmware and I'm comfortable setting up port forwarding and limiting by IP.

Would you recommend looking into setting up a VPN or continue limiting access by IP that I can then change whenever I'm somewhere new (in-laws, parents etc. that don't have a static IP)?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

You'd have less hassle in setting up a VPN. You don't always know if your IP somewhere else will stay the same or change over the course of your session out, or maybe you can't predict what your IP will be (coffee shop, etc)

The VPN setup would mean this wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In a linux guest the easiest would be to use [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com), a featureful, secure remote shell solution that can tunnel traffic bidirectionally, including X sessions and dynamic Socks proxying. It's very popular for the use you mention.